# Deploy файла war на heroku включая дополнительные файлы

Tags: java, heroku, развертывание, war

Загружаю файл `war` на `heroku` и хочу добавить к нему дополнительный файл `*.properties` как описано здесь:

[Configuring WAR Deployment with the Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/configuring-war-deployment-with-the-heroku-toolbelt#including-files)

```
$ heroku war:deploy application.war --app awesomeapp --jdk 14 --includes app1.properties
```

Сам файл `war` загружается нормально, но ни в одной подпапке в развернутом приложении я не могу найти файл `app1.properties`. Вместе с этим, все остальные файлы из архива `war` находятся на своих местах, дополнительный файл `tomcat` `war-tracker` и больше ничего. Если добавить туда какой-либо `jar` файл - результат такой же:

```
$ heroku war:deploy application.war --app awesomeapp --jdk 14 --includes app1.properties:some-lib.jar
```

**Вопрос:** куда `heroku` загружает дополнительные файлы? Как получить туда доступ?

Вот выхлоп [heroku-cli](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli):

```
Uploading application.war
-----> Packaging application...
       - app: awesomeapp
       - including: app1.properties
       - including: some-lib.jar
       - including: webapp-runner.jar
       - including: application.war
-----> Creating build...
       - file: slug.tgz
       - size: 30MB
-----> Uploading build...
       - success
-----> Deploying...
remote:
remote: -----> heroku-deploy app detected
remote: -----> Installing JDK 14... done
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 96.9M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v14
remote:        https://awesomeapp.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
-----> Done
```

---

<sup>См. [Deploy war file to heroku including additional files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61532148/11141611).</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как выяснилось, эти файлы загружаются в корневой каталог приложения в контейнере `heroku`, но не добавляются в папку развернутого приложения.

Проверить это можно, выполнив команду в `web-console` на их сайте: `heroku run bash`, затем `ls`, или `cat app1.properties`.

Чтобы получить доступ к этим файлам из приложения, можно сделать так:

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "app1.properties";
```

Либо можно добавить аннотацию к классу конфигурации в `spring`:

```
@PropertySource(value="file:${user.home}/app1.properties", encoding="UTF-8")
```