# Как лучше хранить файлы в проекте на Heroku?

Tags: java, база-данных, spring, heroku

Каким образом лучше всего хранить файлы в проекте на `Heroku`?

Можно ли хранить их локально, аналогично тому как они хранятся на компьютере? Или их нужно сохранять в базу, с типом данных `Blob` и конвертировать в картинки, `excel` и т. д., только тоже, отдельный вопрос: как? Или извратиться и сохранять файлы в облако, например на `dropbox`, а в базе просто указать ссылку на этот файл?

Answer (score 1):

Просто в проекте можно хранить как статические ресурсы, базы данных здесь не нужны. Или если очень хочется попробовать, тогда попробуй все варианты! Можно заодно время замерить.

Как это сделать?

Ресурсы проекта (вместе со всем проектом) собираются в архив `jar` / `war` и деплоятся на `heroku`. Или можно закомитить проект в `git` в разобранном виде вместе с ресурсами и с файлом `pom` / `gradle` - тогда `heroku` собирёт проект сам.

---

Если нужно файл с настройками к проекту добавить или что-то подобное:

- [Deploy файла war на heroku включая дополнительные файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1126574/328896).

См. также:

- [Как хранить фото для товара в БД?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1165043/328896)
- [Как сохранить базу данных для Heroku?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1168096/328896)