# Как сохранить базу данных для Heroku?

Tags: java, база-данных, heroku, cassandra

Хочу выгрузить свой проект на Heroku, имеется база данных Cassandra в 4500 строк. Возможно ли эти данные сразу загрузить вместе с проектом?

Answer (score 0):

На `heroku` есть свои расширения [add-ons](https://elements.heroku.com/addons), в т. ч. с базами данных, в т. ч. [Instaclustr Apache Cassandra](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/instaclustr), только в данном случае бесплатной версии у них нет. Как альтернативу можно использовать [Heroku Postgres](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql), ограничения в бесплатной версии: 1 GB, 10 000 строчек, 20 подключений. Можно выбрать что-то из этого и перелить туда данные. Можно подключить [H2 Database Engine](http://h2database.com/html/main.html) как часть своего проекта без дополнительных расширений и вместе с данными - оно тоже написано на `java`. Ограничения в бесплатной версии ≈ общие ограничения `heroku`.